# Identifying this part used in awnings?

Tags: framing, outdoor, patio

I’ve seen this used in many awnings, but I don’t know what they’re called.

So a few questions:

What’s the name of this part?

Can they be bought separately or are they only sold in kits?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the manufacturer.   For most manufacturers this is an awning **arm**.   However a lot of times if an arm is detached from the awning unit to rest on the home it is referred to as a **pole**.